# Passing variables to ajax with onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a problem with the variables, that I want to pass through ajax to php.

In an php file, I generate some divs with id and name attributes.

livesrc.php

```
echo "<div class=\"search-results\" id=\"" . $softwareArray['Sw_idn'] . "\" 
name=\"" . $softwareArray['SoftwareName'] . "\" 
onclick=\"addBasket(this.id, this.name)\" >
" . utf8_encode($softwareArray['SoftwareName']) . "</div>";
```

The relevent part is this:

```
onclick="addBasket(this.id, this.name)
```

Sorry for the escapes, in html the div looks like:

```
<div class="search-results" id="235" 
name="Adobe Acrobat Writer 9.0 Professional"
onclick="addBasket(this.id, this.name)">...</div>
```

This looks okay, but in the js "addBasket", the variable sw_name is not set. (undefinded)

The JS in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addBasket(sw_id, sw_name) 
  {
    alert(sw_name);
    $.post("assets/basket.php",{sw_id: sw_id, sw_name: sw_name}, function(data) 
  { 
      $("#basket").html(data);
    });
  }
</script>
```

The sw_id is set, but the sw_name is not working. Is the call in html with "this.name" correct?

Comment: Try `$(this).attr("name")`

Comment: Could you try `$(this).attr('name')` ? (if you're using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's because `this.name` did not exists if you want to access the attribute you have to call `this.getAttribute('name')` id are particular and can be access directly.

Personally I will give juste this to the function and extract id and name in the function

```
 onclick="addBasket(this)";




<script type="text/javascript">
  function addBasket(el) 
  {
    var 
    sw_id = el.id,
    sw_name = $(el).attr('name');

    alert(sw_name);
    $.post("assets/basket.php",{sw_id: sw_id, sw_name: sw_name}, function(data) 
  { 
      $("#basket").html(data);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what does it mean that "el" in this term     sw_id = el.id,
    sw_name = $(el).attr('name');

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the whole element into your js:

```
<div class="search-results" id="235" 
name="Adobe Acrobat Writer 9.0 Professional"
onclick="addBasket(this)">...</div>
```

Then grab what you want in your function

```
function addBasket(sw) {
    alert( sw.id + ' ' + sw.getAttribute( 'name' ) );
}
```